# Event handler item:saved - failing?

Tags: sitecore

I have the following .cs file;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Events;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;

namespace LocationItemEventHandler
{
    public class ItemEventHandler
    {
        private static readonly SynchronizedCollection<ID> MProcess = new SynchronizedCollection<ID>();

        /// <summary>
        /// This custom event auto-populates latitude/longitude co-ordinate when a location item is saved
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        protected void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

            if (item != null && !MProcess.Contains(item.ID))
            {
                if (item.TemplateID.Equals("{E490971E-758E-4A75-9C8D-67EC2C6321CA}"))
                {
                    string errMessage = "";
                    string responseCode = "";
                    string address = item.Fields["Address"].Value;
                    if (1=1)
                    {
                        string latitude = "100";
                        string longitude = "200";

                        MProcess.Add(item.ID);

                        try
                        {
                            var latlngField = item.Fields["Google LatLng"];
                            using (new SecurityDisabler())
                            {
                                item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                                latlngField.SetValue(latitude + " - " + longitude, true);
                                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert(
                                string.Format(
                                "Fields updated automatically\r\nLatitude: {0}\r\nLongitude: {1}",
                                latitude, longitude));
                                item.Editing.EndEdit();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Log.Error(exception.Message, this);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            MProcess.Remove(item.ID);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is in a code file `LocationItemEventHandler.cs` in `App_Code`. 
this is in the web.config

```
<event name="item:saved">
<handler type="LocationItemEventHandler.ItemEventHandler, LocationItemEventHandler" method="OnItemSaved"/>
</event>
```

When i try to save an item i get a "Could not resolve type name".

What am i missing?

Comment: Have you verified that you have a .dll in the bin folder named LocationItemEventHandler or even have a reference to that assembly? Sitecore is an application and therefore it's not going to look in the app_code folder. You need to have a dll and a reference to it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name you have configured does not match the actual class name.

Edit:
If the handler is in App_Code, i believe you should leave off the assembly name in the type reference. Better yet, don't use App_Code.

Comment: Sorry - a typo.

<handler type="LocationItemEventHandler.ItemEventHandler, LocationItemEventHandler" method="OnItemSaved"/>

namespace LocationItemEventHandler
public class ItemEventHandler

Comment: So, just a typo from my part. The above is correct - and it gives the mentioned error when saving.

Comment: Edited, I think your assembly name is the issue then.